# want to find the solution of extensions in python

Tags: python

I am new to python any facing some problem in it.
I want to make a script in python which take two inputs:
1. path to dir
2. file extension to remove

If user type the path and extension to remove then what i want is that the file extension typed by the user save in a list and when the file read by the interpretor it automatically remove the extension file.

Here is the code:

```
import os
Ext_list = []
path=raw_input('Enter the path for Scanning : ')
while True:
    x = raw_input('Enter the extension: ')
    if x == ' ':
        break
    Ext_list.append(x)

for (path, subdirs, filesnames) in os.walk(path):
    if filesnames is (x):
        os.remove(filesnames)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes could not post the image due to reputation

Comment: paste the code, past it on it and then ctrl+k to modify so that stackoverflow can understand it is code

Comment: I answered with solutioin

Comment: already tried your solution before this code but couldn't get that logic.

Comment: See if that works. You have to modify it yourself. I tried it and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Use this, of course you have to modify it

```
glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.path*'))
```

it will output an array of the files with that extention. And then.

```
input = str(raw_input("Please enter file extention "))
files = glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.'+input.))
for File in files:
    os.remove(File)
```

Comment: Also the star is to tell python to get all the files. If you have just the star it will get all the files indipendent of the extention